# How to avoid the stretching of Images in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I trying to put images programmatically .But when I putting the images they are getting stretched. I am using Micromax Canvas to view my application.

This is my code

```
void populateData(){
        populate=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.populate);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.weight=1.0f;

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            LinearLayout hr_populate=new LinearLayout(this);
            hr_populate.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spicejet);

            img.setLayoutParams(params);
            ImageView img1=new ImageView(this);
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.book);
            img1.setLayoutParams(params);
            ImageView img2=new ImageView(this);
            img2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow);
            img2.setLayoutParams(params);

            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setText("BOS");
            text.setLayoutParams(params);
            TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
            text1.setText("SAN");
            text1.setLayoutParams(params);
            TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
            text2.setText("6h15m");
            text2.setLayoutParams(params);
            TextView text3 = new TextView(this);
            text3.setText("32,163");
            text3.setLayoutParams(params);

            LinearLayout book_div = new LinearLayout(this);
            book_div.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            book_div.setLayoutParams(params);

            book_div.addView(text3);
            book_div.addView(img1);

            hr_populate.addView(img);
            hr_populate.addView(text);
            hr_populate.addView(text1);
            hr_populate.addView(text2);
            hr_populate.addView(book_div);
            hr_populate.addView(img2);
            populate.addView(hr_populate);
        }
    }
```

This is my XML code

```
<ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sortFlightLayouts">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/populate"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Please suggest me what changes I have to make to get out from this issue

Comment: Take a look at the ImageView property adjustViewBounds.

Comment: @Stacks28 I have to do this programmatically .so please suggest for that what I have to do

Comment: did u tried Kartik solution ? did it worked?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the ImageView's scaleType to fitCenter. Here is a good example of the different scale types: http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html

Comment: I have to do this programmatically .

Comment: Use setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType)

Answer (score 0):

As nspace suggested, you can set [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for ImageView. You can use [setScaleType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29) method of ImageView.

```
eg. imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

There are various options for scaling image. You can get all types from [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) class.

**Update:**

Instead of setting image background, set image drawable using [setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method of ImageView and then apply above scaling code if required.

ie:
remove : `img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spicejet);`

add : `imag.setImageResource(R.drawable.spicejet);`

Comment: I tried this as  img1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            img1.setLayoutParams(params); But it not working same issue

Comment: Try with Center or FitCenter

Comment: where I have to put this code I am putting this after img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.book);

Comment: @GauravPandey : The problem is you are setting up background instead of setting up drawable resource. I have updated answer.

Comment: now it is overlapping on my Book Button my code is           img1.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow));
            img1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_END);

Comment: You will have to find out why its overlapping as I don't know how yoru layout is. Debug and correct.

Comment: I have posted in my question my layout and the java code please suggest I am not getting I am new in android development thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33771/discussion-between-gaurav-pandey-and-kartik)